# Android Add image to listviewitem after click on button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-listview

In my application I have a listview with products. Above the listview in the actionbar I have a button "edit list". When you click on the button I want to add an image to each listviewitem in the listview. When you click on the image you delete it from the list. Now I added an imageview to the listviewitem and set die visibility to gone.

But I don't know how to change the visibility with a click on a button.

So the question: How do you add an imageview in listviewitem with click on button? Or how do you change the visibility property of an imageview in an Listviewitem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static parameter like `int uiUpdate=0` and use an adapter to add data to list view and check uiUpdate in getView of your adapter. When user click on button set uiUpdate=1 and reffresh your list with this : `yourlist.setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter);`
in getView of EfficientAdapter check value of uiUpdate if it's 1 set visibility VISIBLE : `yourimageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` efficientAdapter is something like this : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html